# OpenGL: Performance of drawing a single gigantic primative

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

If I draw a massive primitive whose bounds far exceed the viewing area, like a quad that covers 50,000 to -50,000 in X and Y (in NDC space), will OpenGL clip the primitive such that it performs just as well as if the quad only barely exceeded NDC space boundaries (1.1 to -1.1 for instance)?

The reason I ask is I need to draw a grid to debug the camera and how it's viewing a space, and I'm wondering if I can skip manually clipping how long the grid lines are drawn.

Comment: If this is just for debug purposes, then why not try it and see?

Comment: @immibis - I don't have complex enough of a scene to test it against, so the results I got are kinda the same between the two versions.  I guess I'm asking out of curiousity more than anything, if I'll need to clip the grid if the scene gets more complex, or if OpenGL will do it better than I can automatically.

Comment: Frustum culling is done before anything is actually rendered, so no time will be spent trying to draw something that won't be visible. More important than dimensions, are the number of pixels actually drawn, as well as the complexity of the object.

Comment: You may encounter precision problems if you make it too large, so just be aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hardware performs clipping the way it's described in the spec, drawing a gigantic primitive will be the same performance as one that is just barely larger than the clip volume. According to the spec, clipping happens in clip coordinate space, by modifying the vertex coordinates coming out of the vertex shader, and adding new vertices if necessary.

This doesn't guarantee that clipping happens this way, though. As always, implementations are free to do anything they want, as long as they behave **as if** they followed the spec description. All we know for sure that clipping happens based on the vertices coming out of the vertex shader, and that fragments that would be outside the clip volume will not enter the fragment shader.

How exactly the invisible parts are eliminated in the fixed function blocks between vertex and fragment shaders is completely up to the implementation. On some hardware, it may happen in vertex space. Others might rasterize first, and then eliminate the potential fragments that would be outside the window (or scissor rectangle). Or they might use a mix of both methods, depending on various criteria.

So it's possible that drawing gigantic primitives could be slower because it can result in extra rasterization overhead. The only way to know if this is indeed the case on systems you care about, and if it causes a measurable effect, is to try it out and measure.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially 3 main sources of performance trouble in OpenGL. The following is a very simplified very technically wrong explanation of what can be wrong if your framerate is insufficient:

- The CPU: This is your bottleneck if you do too much computation or too many draw calls or glGets.
- The vertex stage: this is your bottleneck if you supply too many vertices, your vertices are poorly specified or you have a very complex vertex shader.
- The fragment stage: this is your bottleneck if you draw at too high a resolution, draw pixels over eachother often, or have very complex fragment shaders.

So if we compare the two scenario's, the draw calls stay the same, the vertices stay the same, and the fragments? Stay the same as well. 
As glank already mentioned in the comments, OpenGL will only spawn and compute fragments if they might eventually show up on the screen, and will not waste time with stuff outside of the viewing frustum. The effects of this are easy to notice, simply render something with a complex shader, then look away from it, your framerate will go up, but you don't do any manual culling. Fantastic.

Keep in mind that, for most complex scenario's, simply trying out the performance of various approaches is the only way to say something useful about their performance.